# Convert properties from properties file into json in Dataweave 2.0

Tags: mule, dataweave, mule-esb

How to convert properties from a properties file

```
creditmaster.metadata.AverageFicoScore=700
creditmaster.a.b.c=xyz
```

into this json format in a generic way

```
{
  creditmasterMetaData: [
     {
       attributeKey: "AverageFicoScore",
       attributeValue: 700
     }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Please provide more details of the logic that needs to be applied for this transformation. Is that the only possible property? I suspect not, or you would not ask to do in a generic way. What happens if there are other properties? Does every attribute has `.metadata.` in the middle?

Comment: "creditmaster.metadata.AverageFicoScore=700" getting this from properties file, and there are many properties. but "creditmaster" is common. @aled

Comment: What is the criteria for entries that are ignored? You should provide all these details in advance because we can not guess them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This script is generic in that it doesn't matter what are the parts of the key, it only groups by the first element (before of the first dot) and the key name after the last dot, it ignores everything in the middle:

```
%dw 2.3
output application/java
import * from dw::core::Strings

fun mapProperties(props) = 
    entriesOf(props) // since Mule 4.3 / DW 2.3
        filter (substringAfter($.key, ".") startsWith "metadata.") // to filter keys with .metadata.
        groupBy ((item, index) -> substringBefore(item.key, ".")) 
        mapObject ((value, key, index) ->  
            (key): value map {
                attributeKey: substringAfterLast($.key, "."),
                attributeValue: if (isInteger($.value)) $.value as Number else $.value
            }
        )
---
mapProperties(payload)
```

Input file:

```
creditmaster.metadata.AverageFicoScore= 700
other.a.b= 123
creditmaster.a.b.c=xyz
something.metadata.another.maximum=456
creditmaster.metadata.different.minimum=500
```

Output (in JSON for clarity):

```
{
  "something": [
    {
      "attributeKey": "maximum",
      "attributeValue": "456"
    }
  ],
  "creditmaster": [
    {
      "attributeKey": "minimum",
      "attributeValue": "500"
    },
    {
      "attributeKey": "AverageFicoScore",
      "attributeValue": "700"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: When i am passing payload getting Error - "Expecting Object but passing Binary"

Comment: In payload "creditmaster.metadata.AverageFicoScore=700" is the data coming from a properties file, and I am passing this payload in the function. but getting above error.

Comment: How are you reading the properties file into the payload?

Comment: I added a filter for `.metadata.` in keys, and input output examples to show how it works for me. I send the file through HTTP to an HTTP Listener. You have to set the MIME content type that DataWeave is expecting to recognize the format (application/x-java-properties).

Comment: I am reading the properties file using the "read file" component in Mule and using the payload for further process.

Comment: In that case you might need to set the outputMimeType attribute to force the  MIME type application/x-java-properties. Otherwise DataWeave has no way to know it is not a binary file.

Answer (score 1):

One alternative is using the `pluck` function. It lets you iterate over an object receiving the entries.

If you have this input

```
{
  "creditmaster": {
    "metadata": {
      "AverageFicoScore": "700",
      "OtherData": "Some value"
    }
  }
}
```

with this transformation

```
{
  creditmasterMetaData:
    payload.creditmaster.metadata pluck ((value, key, index) -> 
      {
        attributeKey: key,
        attributeValue: value
      }
    )
}
```

you get this output

```
{
  "creditmasterMetaData": [
    {
      "attributeKey": "AverageFicoScore",
      "attributeValue": "700"
    },
    {
      "attributeKey": "OtherData",
      "attributeValue": "Some value"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: I have to generate dynamically this part "creditmasterMetaData"  also, how to do??/

Comment: There are multiple properties in the property file and "creditmaster" is common and rest are different and I have to convert properties in json object as you have mentioned in output. How to write generic code for that??

Comment: Hi Hassan. Does the structure come with different levels or it's always a fixed number? In this case would be two: "credit" and "metadata".

Comment: Structure can be different levels like - "creditmaster.bms.upfront.saopUrl" in all structure "creditmaster" part is common.